# C# Invoke powershell "Get-Website" always return empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, iis, web-testing

I'm trying to read my IIS local websites from C# using Powershell
But I always get an empty output

```
public static ManageWebsite GetWebSiteStatus(string websiteName)
{

    ManageWebsite websiteState = new ManageWebsite();
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();

    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(); // Create a new PowerShell instance
    ps.Runspace = runspace; // Add the instance to the runspace
    ps.Commands.AddScript(@"Get-Website -Name """ + websiteName + @""" | %{$_.state}"); // Add a script

    Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
    string powershell_output = string.Empty;

    runspace.Close();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        powershell_output = obj.BaseObject.ToString();

    }

    websiteState.Status = powershell_output;
    websiteState.WebSite = websiteName;
    return websiteState;
}
```

I don't know why, I always use that function to invoke other things with powershell in C# and always works fine

Answer (score 0):

a few things to check:

you instanciate a stringbuilder but never use it

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

you set a variable to an empty string, which is ok but you override it everytime you loop through your objects. IF you never get objects its still an empty  string! An then you assign to Status websiteState.Status.

```
   string powershell_output = string.Empty; 
   foreach (PSObject obj in results)
   {
       powershell_output = obj.BaseObject.ToString();
   }

   websiteState.Status = powershell_output;
```

So if your websiteName never gets an result from Get-Website you will always have an Object with no Properites set as expected. If you get an result from Get-Website you only get some stuff form BaseObject.ToString() from the last iterated object. You might want to do a little more checking if you get something back at all before you try to assign values.

**Update to comments**

you might want to build your string like

```
ps.Commands.AddScript($"Get-Website -Name {websiteName} | %{{$_.state}}");
```

and i am not sure if you get to access the pipe result with this like you expect it in powershell. so maybe try to  store the array in a OutVariable that you return explict in the script.

Comment: You are right, but any way if I debug on "Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();" this ps.invoke is returning empty data when must get the results

Comment: i would look at line ps.Commands.AddScript(@"Get-Website -Name """ + websiteName + @""" | %{$_.state}"); does it  creates a coorect script to pass in and invoke later.

Comment: But if I try other things like ps.Commands.AddScript(@"Get-Acl"); it returns values. The problem just happend with "Get-Website"

Comment: do you pass arguments to the other commands or try to pipe commands like in the code ypu showed? you also need to consider if the script is able to run where you invoke it  and how you invoke it. Does the command need different rights to run then your  code runs it. easiest way to find out if you get what you expect is to run the code in a powershell cmd (not ISE!!!)  and if it successful runs try to pass it with out the pipe first and inspect the result you get back from it

Comment: a lot of smart people out in the world of computer science have given us advice on how to approach problmes and one of them is to incremtal solve problems so start with a simple get-website and work your way up to getting results with a piped output

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all.
I know I'm an idiot. My code  ps.Commands.AddScript(@"Get-Website -Name """ + websiteName + @""" | %{$_.state}"); // Add a script
is acting in the IIS Express, that's why always return empty

Comment: You might one day hit more differences, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 So it is very important to know the execution context.

Comment: I request you to mark the solution as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issues.